# Multiplying columns in Power BI results in #ERROR

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm multiplying two columns in Power BI using DAX to get a charge. One column is a quantity and the other the amount. The operation can't be calculated, the error message I receive states "The result of a conversion or arithmetic operation is either too large or too small".

One column is a currency the other is data type and format "Decimal number" with the number of decimal places set to 1. No charge should be more than 6 figures so I'm not sure why it would be too large or too small.

```
= 'table1'[columnA]*'table1'[columnB]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Data type of the column to `Decimal Number`.
Or
Another reason could be an invalid value in one of your rows.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that isn't correcting the error and no combination of data type and format seems to correct it.

Comment: Then please share a sample pbix, or update your question with a sample table so that we can re-produce the error.

Comment: There was a non number value in one of the columns that was producing the error, I corrected it by using the IFERROR function